# Code Igniter: Form's action cannot direct to the right path

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, path

I'm working on Code Igniter Project.

I have a php file in the view folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\MSPN\APPLICATION\views`

The form is written like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url() .'homeSignUp/main'; ?>" method="post" >
```

In the browser, the file is located in `localhost/mspn/index.php/signup/main`

In the config.php I have:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/mspn/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

The form 'action' is meant to direct to the `homeSignUp.php` in the `controller` folder that has a method `main`.

But when I tried to run it, the `submit` button directed to `localhost/mspn/homeSignUp/main`.
And it said: Object not found!

I've been trying to change the url in the `action`attribute, yet it keeps giving me that error.
What have I missed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change `index_page` config to:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Then use `site_url()` like:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('homeSignUp/main'); ?>" method="post" >
```

**Note:** Since it seems you are using a specific `route`, you might want to use `signup/main` instead of `homeSignUp/main`.

Because the site url will includes both `base_url` and also the `index_url` if any. So you dont need to mention `index.php` seperatly.

Comment: I've tried to do so, but it still doesn't work. I've been at it for about 5 hours, and it keeps giving me 'Object not found!'. What do I do?

Comment: can you show us the main function in homeSignUp controller..?"

Comment: Yea, but it's sorta long. Can I post it into the answer here or shall I upload the file somewhere?

Comment: I mean to say that may be there is an prob in your function

Comment: I have upload the screen shoot of some of the code here: http://s24.postimg.org/7k5wh9adh/CODE.png

Comment: Thanks! >< You helped me out of my five-hour-fight. :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all remove the `index.php` from your url by using `.htaccess` then your url should look like this

```
localhost/mspn/signup/main

//Remove index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Prevents user access to the application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And your `config.php` should have this configuration

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Then your form should look like this

```
echo form_open(base_url()."homeSignUp/main");
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: I've been trying to remove that index.php out of the path. But I kept failing. Now it is still there..